# Tricky SQL grouping query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table which tracks items dispensed.  The main data I have is a TransactionID, TransactionDateTime, PersonID, CostCentre, ProductID, TransactionType, and Quantity.

I need to transform this table to only show the items dispensed and used.

Now my issue is that in some cases, a product may be distributed, say 25 of that item, and then for some reason it may be returned, either entirely, or partially.  So either 25 come back, or 15 come back.  The resulting record needs to identify the correct amount distributed.

To signify a return, the Quantity field is negative, and the TransactionType is DSPN-  as oppose to DSPN for a standard transaction.

In most cases the TransactionID is the same for both the dispensed and return transaction, resulting in a simple Group By function.  However I have found cases where this isn't the case, and was wondering if there is another solution to grouping these records together.

What I have so far is just the basic group.

`SELECT dspn_id AS DspnID, SUM([Qty]) AS Qty,  MIN(creationDate) AS RIO, MIN(TransactionID) AS PKey
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY dspn_id
    HAVING SUM(Qty) > 0`

Sample data of standard situation where I can group by dspn_id:
`dspn_id      creationDate       PersonID  CostCenter ProdID  TranType   QTY
972490  2012-10-08 12:14:46.440 984254875   CostCC1 4591    DSPN    25
972487  2012-10-08 12:14:46.463 984254875   CostCC1 1017    DSPN    30
972490  2012-10-08 12:15:24.270 984254875   CostCC1 4591    DSPN-   -25
972487  2012-10-08 12:15:38.990 984254875   CostCC1 1017    DSPN-   -30
972496  2012-10-08 12:15:51.490 984254875   CostCC1 4591    DSPN    25
972497  2012-10-08 12:15:51.500 984254875   CostCC1 1017    DSPN    30`

Sample data of where my issue is:
`dspn_id      creationDate       PersonID  CostCenter ProdID  TranType   QTY
962376  2012-09-21 16:01:03.783 123456789   CostCC2 18007   DSPN    2
962998  2012-09-24 09:31:20.433 123456789   CostCC2 18007   DSPN-   -1`

I could simply group up by CostCenter and ProdID, but this is not the solution I'm after.  Ideally, in the above situation, I would have a single record for ProdID 18007 that shows a date of 2012-09-21 16:01:03.783 and QTY of 1.  Even if that same ProdID was distributed to that PersonID with that CostCentre.

Comment: You need to edit your question with sample data.  If the transaction id doesn't tie records together, what does?

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff. Some sample data as well as desired results would be extremely helpful! :D

Comment: It might be easier if you show your schema as well.  What are your tables and what fields do they have

Comment: In your sample data, what do you expect dspn_id to be in case you aggregated the two rows into one row like you want?

Comment: Not overly bothered, probably the first dspn_id though.

Comment: Why not group by `PersonId`, `CostCenter`, and `ProdId`?

Comment: Because I only want to group where there has been a return.

Comment: The bigger problem with grouping by PersonId, CostCenter, and ProdId is that it may group transactions with ones from months or years ago, if the same person is on the same CostCenter and is given the same Product.  Can you use a date range restriction in a Having clause?

Comment: @Matt . . . You need to edit your question with the rules you want to implement.

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is "How do I know the products being returned are the product they purchased in a specific transaction?". If there is no way to relate the return to a specific sale, then you won't be able to match the transaction.

Comment: Thats the conclusion I've come to Tsarin.  I think I'm going to have to go back to the source data and have it corrected there.  I was hoping there would be another way. Oh well, thanks for the help.